# Open pages with user lists and download the user ids

Tags: javascript

So I have a page which has a list of users, my total list of users is separated into 10 pages with each page showing 20 users. I want to open each page in a new window, pull the user ids on that window, close the window, and open the next page. Later I'll compile all this into a report. The problem I seem to be having is that the user_id_list only gets populated by the users on the first page so I have a bunch of duplicates.

Some of the code for parsing the pages.

```
full_page_string = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination")[0].outerText;
index_of_next = full_page_string.lastIndexOf("Next");
last_page_number = full_page_string.substring(index_of_next-3, index_of_next);
last_page_number.trim();


last_page_number = 2; /*DELETE LATER*/
page_array = [];
user_id_list = [];

/*Programatically create an array of pages*/
for (var page_num = 1; page_num <= last_page_number; page_num++) {

    url = "example.com/users/"+ user_account_id + "/friends?page=" + page_num;

    /*Open Each Page*/
    var loaded_page = window.open(url, "page_" + page_num, "width=400, height=600");

    page_array.push(loaded_page)

    /*
    For loop keps going even with settimeout. See if there is a way to delay a forloop. The thing is we need enough time to load a page, wait for it, grab users, close page, load a new page and repeat. Right now the floor loop makes it too fast.

    Maybe Asyncronously open each page so they're their own instance or "thread"?
    */

    loaded_page.onload = function () {
        /*Find all users on the page by class*/                
        friends_on_page = document.getElementsByClassName("link span f5 fw7 secondary");
        for (var i = 0; i <= friends_on_page.length; i++) {
            pathname = friends_on_page[i].pathname;
            user_id = pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
            user_id_list.push(user_id)
            console.log(user_id)
        }
        loaded_page.cose()
    };

}
```